# Query min value at x of many equations in the form |x-a| + b

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, line, cartesian-coordinates

Kind of unrelated to what I was doing, but I stumbled on this interesting data structure. I can't figure out a few details.

Suppose I have like N<10^5 equations in the form y = |x-a| + b, with 0 < x, a, b < 10^5. After O(N) preprocessing, for any x, I want to find the minimum value out of all these equations in constant time.

Here's what I have so far: add the functions one by one in increasing values of a, **somehow find the intersection between the new function and the min existing function**, then store intersections. The intersections can tell us what equation to use for the min. Then we can use binary search for log time queries, but since x<10^5, we can just go through all values and precompute the correct min value for each x

Visualization, where the black is the min values

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic property of modulus is

```
1. |x| = x if x>=0
2. |x| = -x if x<0
```

Using this, the equation `y = |x-a|+b` can be written as

```
1. y = x + (b-a) if x >= a
2. y = (b+a) - x if x<a
```

Since `b` and `a` are constants, we can use pre-computation to get answers per query in constant time.
For a given `x`, there are two cases:

1. The minima lies to the left of `x` (i.e. `a < x`). If we know the minimum value of `b-a` for all lines with `a < x`, we can get the answer in O(1) time.
2. Similarly, when the minima lies on the right of `x` (i.e. `a >= x`), if we know the minimum value of `b+a` for all lines with `a >= x`, we can get the answer in O(1) time.

To summarise, we need to know the minimum value of `b-a` for all `a` on the left of `x` and the minimum value of `b+a` for all `a` on the right of `x`. This can easily be done using a simple [prefix and/or suffix array](https://dev.to/grekz/prefix-sum-suffix-sum-programming-tools-1eh5) implementation.

Comment: wait your 1. and 2. should be reversed right? I think you switched a and x in your inequalities.